# How can I sync a folder *to* android using syncthing?

Tags: applications

I have installed [syncthing](https://syncthing.net/) on my [Windows desktop](https://syncthing.net/) and on my [android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nutomic.syncthingandroid) 2.3.3 based phone.  The nodes are talking and I see that I am connected to the windows desktop.  I successfully sync'd a folder from my mobile phone to the desktop, so I believe the connection is working.  The Android UI shows the connection as present to the desktop.

I selected the mobile phone device in the "Share With Devices" section of the desktop folder' configuration from the desktop syncthing localhost web UI, but I can't figure out how to add the Windows directory to be sync'd onto the phone.

In the Android syncthing UI, how can I sync an entire folder from the desktop machine to the mobile phone?

*Meta:

I hope this is [on-topic](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).  The on-topic blurb seems to suggest that it is:*

> *If your question generally covers...*
>   *[...]*
>   *Using a particular app on your Android device*

Answer (score 5):

Here's what I did.

Firstly I was in the same situation - devices were visible to each other, windows had the files, android did not.

I created a folder on android with syncthing and gave it the same name as my folder on the PC ( not essential ) but crucially, I used the same folder ID as the folder on the server.

Then I selected the server ( slide switch on ) and saved my folder in android. Now they are syncing files.

Summary make sure your folders have the same folder ID (on the general tab).

Hope this helps. Please give it approved answer if it solves.

Comment: This worked for me!